# Git: start over

Tags: git, github

I have an online repository that I've cloned locally and then worked on. I've managed to mess up the local repo quite a bit and since the original online repo is untouched, I figured that it would be probably the most practical just to scrub my local repo and start from scratch. But I don't want to create an even bigger mess by not removing local repo correctly - so, how does one do it properly?

(Let's say that my repo is in a folder MyRepo and inside I have the .git folder - I understood that I should just delete this .git folder, but since it is inside the MyRepo I am not sure it will delete everything?)

A second question - about good practices for the future... Let's say I make changes locally and then want to upload them online (i have one collaborator so there shouldn't be too much mess). Is it a good practice to do the following: pull* (to update my local repository), commit, push?
Should I be checking for other stuff also?

*another thing I don't quite understand - let's say that after doing pull, a file was changed locally - but this is the file that I was also working on at the time (and didn't commit yet) - will my local version get overwritten? What to do in this case?

Comment: Look for a good tutorial on Youtube or read an introductory guide, these aren’t bad questions but they are basic fundamentals so it’s worth investing some time to learn the proper workflow and commands.

Comment: Delete the MyRepo directory and re-clone the repository.

Comment: You remove a local checkout by simply removing it. `rm -rf` for example.

Comment: But please ask one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

If you cloned the repository, and then on a certain branch you did work which didn't go in the right direction, then consider doing a hard reset to get back to the starting commit of that branch:

```
git reset --hard
```

Regarding your second question, a typical pull-based workflow might look like this:

- do your work, and make one or more commits
- then `git pull` to sync up with the latest changes in the remote branch
- `git push` to push your work to the remote branch

Note that after pulling, you might have merge conflicts, which would have to be resolved, and committed, before you could push.